# SQL Server : most common value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Accessoires_OrderDetails` with the following structure:

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1)
accessoireID int,
QteSelled int,
Price Varchar(50)
```

I am using this query to display the most sold item in the table:

```
SELECT TOP 12 
    AccessoireID, COUNT(AccessoireID) AS Amount 
FROM 
    Accessoires_OrderDetails
GROUP BY 
    AccessoireID
ORDER BY 
    Amount DESC
```

But I don't know how to display the `Qte` sold.

The output of that query is :

```
1   3
4   2
2   1
```

I want the show that item id = 1 was sold 3 times.

Example:

```
AccessoireID = 1, Sold = 3 times, first time (Qte = 2), second time (Qte = 3), third time (Qte = 5)
```

The output should be

```
1   3  10 
4   2
2   1
```

So 10 is the number of `Qte` sold for all the sales.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? Also, tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: @GurV i edited my question

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on `identity` and `top`

Comment: Past tense of "to sell" is "sold" - not "selled" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple SUM will do:

```
select TOP 12 
    AccessoireID,
    count(AccessoireID) as Amount,
    SUM(QTE) as total_qte           -- Added this
from Accessoires_OrderDetails
GROUP BY AccessoireID
ORDER BY Amount
DESC
```